# Sending Notification With Firebase Cloud Functions to Specific users

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase cloud function in my firebase group chat app, Setup is already done but problem is when some one send message in any group then all user get notification for that message including non members of group.

I want to send notification to group specific users only, below is my code for firebase cloud function -

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const _ = require('lodash');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNewMessageNotification = functions.database.ref('/{pushId}').onWrite(event => {
const getValuePromise = admin.database()
                             .ref('messages')
                             .orderByKey()
                             .limitToLast(1)
                             .once('value');

return getValuePromise.then(snapshot => {
   const { text, author } = _.values(snapshot.val())[0];

    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: text,
            body: author,
            icon: ''
        }
    };

    return admin.messaging()
                .sendToTopic('my-groupchat', payload);
 });
});
```

This will be really help full, if anyway some one can suggest on this.

Comment: The code looks correct, so I assume the issue is in the way you are subscribing the members to the topic, can you share how are you subscribing the members of the topic?

Comment: In my code i am passing only {pushId} so its generate notification when any write operation is performed on  database, but i want notification when write operation is performed in a group and user is member of that group.

Comment: is `my-groupchat` the name of the topic where the users that you want to share the message or the whole group of users? If it's the latter you will have to create a separate topic and subscribe members to it, so that only then receive it.

Comment: Whole group of users but not all users in DB, only group members in which message in initiated. So how can i subscribe for every group via cloud function(Groups created dynamically).

Comment: There are a couple of examples in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#top_of_page), you could do it server side, or client side. In your case, you could follow the examples for the server side, since you would need to add them in bulk. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As per our conversation on the comments I believe that the issue is that you are using a topic that contains all the users, which is the `my-groupchat` topic. The solution would be to create a new topic with the users that are part of this subtopic.

As for how to create such topics, there are a couple of examples in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#top_of_page), in there you can see that you could do it server side, or client side. In your case, you could follow the examples for the server side, since you would need to add them in bulk, but as new users are added it could be interesting to implement the client side approach.